# How can I use HAL3/Camera2 API alongwith OpenCV to capture the video from two MIPI cameras?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, gstreamer, robotics

I am using Qualcomm rb5 development kit along with two MIPI camera's OV9282. Somehow I am not able to use Gstreamer with OpenCV to access these stereo cameras. Does anyone knows how to use HAL3 +OpenCV? There aren't basic tutorials on that. I am stuck with this problem. Please help me.

I have tried using Gstreamer pipeline to access those cameras using below code.

```py
import cv2
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import gi

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib

Gst.init(None)

main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
thread = Thread(target=main_loop.run)
thread.start()

pipeline_str = """
    qtiqmmfsrc camera=1 ! video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=15/1 ! videoconvert ! waylandsink 
"""
pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_str)
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

pipeline_str2 = """
    qtiqmmfsrc camera=3 ! video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=15/1 ! videoconvert ! waylandsink
"""
pipeline2 = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_str2)
pipeline2.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline_str2, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

num = 0

while True:
    succes1, img = cap.read()
    succes2, img2 = cap2.read()

    if not succes1 or not succes2:
        break

    cv2.imshow('Img 1', img)
    cv2.imshow('Img 2', img2)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5)

    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        cv2.imwrite('images/stereoLeft/imageL{}.png'.format(num), img)
        cv2.imwrite('images/stereoRight/imageR{}.png'.format(num), img2)
        print('images saved!')
        num += 1

cap.release()
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
pipeline2.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
main_loop.quit()
```

It is only displaying one camera and that camera stream is not getting fed into the rest of the code with VideoCapture function. I don't know what is wrong with it. Hence, I am trying to see if there is other ways to access camera's using HAL3/Camera2 APIs.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code:

- For using a gstreamer pipeline as capture from opencv, the pipeline would have to end with appsink (the opencv application).
- Opencv videocapture will manage the pipeline creation and change states.

First try:

```
import cv2
from time import sleep

pipeline_str = """
    videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=15/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1
"""
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Failed to open capture')
    exit(-1)
    
    
pipeline_str2 = """
    videotestsrc pattern=ball ! video/x-raw, format=NV12, width=1280, height=720, framerate=15/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1
""" 
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline_str2, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if not cap2.isOpened():
    print('Failed to open capture2')
    exit(-2)

num = 0

while True:
    succes1, img = cap.read()
    succes2, img2 = cap2.read()

    if not succes1 or not succes2:
        break

    cv2.imshow('Img 1', img)
    cv2.imshow('Img 2', img2)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5)

    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        cv2.imwrite('images/stereoLeft/imageL{}.png'.format(num), img)
        cv2.imwrite('images/stereoRight/imageR{}.png'.format(num), img2)
        print('images saved!')
        num += 1

cap.release()
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If it works, change the sources with your cameras.

**EDIT:**
It is unclear what is your gstreamer stack with only camera source and waylandsink. If you don't have gstreamer appsink, you may not be able to use opencv VideoCapture that relies on that.

You may however try in such case to add a src pad probe to camera plugin. From the callback, you may be able to get buffer data and put it into an opencv mat or numpy array for further processing. You may push these into fifos or circular buffers to be picked up by the application, checking PTS for synchronization between cameras:

**Callback function:**

```
def probe_callback(pad,info): 
    gst_buffer = info.get_buffer()
    print(' PTS:', gst_buffer.pts)
    ret, mapinfo = gst_buffer.map(Gst.MapFlags.READ)
    if ret:        
        #read the mapped buffer into np frame
        frameNV12 = np.frombuffer(mapinfo.data, dtype=np.uint8)
        frameNV12.shape = ((int)(720*3/2), 1280, 1)
        
        # Convert NV12 into BGR 
        frameBGR = cv2.cvtColor(frameNV12, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12)
                
        # Here you would push a copy of the frame into a queue or circular buffer for application
        # You may attach the pts for checking synchronization between various cameras 
        
        # Or write to disk for checking last image...Note that it may be slow depending on your hw
        #cv2.imwrite("test.png", frameBGR)
        
        del frameBGR
        del frameNV12
        gst_buffer.unmap(mapinfo)
    else:
        print('ERROR: Failed to map buffer')
        
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK
```

**Before starting pipeline, add the probe to src pad of camera source plugin:**

```
srcpad = source.get_static_pad('src')
probeID = srcpad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BUFFER, probe_callback)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that I am limited to qtiqmmfsrc source and waylandsink element on Qualcomm rb5 board. Appsink is anot working. I tried modifying code in a different way, but despite of that I can see only one camera stream playing and it is not getting fed into OpenCV's Videocapture.

Comment: I want to post my code here but I am limited with space. I don't know any other way to capture the video stream directly and feed into the algorithm. I am trying to calculate depth from stereo cameras using OV9282 MIPI cameras.

Comment: I have posted my other code here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75779868/21416083

Comment: You may also edit your original question for further adding details.

It is inclear what is your gstreamer stack with only camera source and waylandsink.

If you don't have gstreamer appsink, you may not be able to use opencv VideoCapture that relies on that.

You may however try in such case to add a src pad probe to camera plugin. From the callback, you may be able to get buffer data and put it into an opencv mat or numpy array for further processing. You may push these into fifos or circular buffers to be picked by application, checking PTS for both frames synchronization.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? This is very high level to me.

Comment: Done. Hpe it helps.