# How to get stereo camera output using Gstreamer+OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera, qualcomm

I have been using Gstreamer on Qualcomm's rb5 board and limited to qtiqmmfsrc and waylandsink element in Gstreamer pipeline. My question is:

1. How can I access OV9282 MIPI stereo camera's using Gstreamer?
2. How to feed that that pipeline to do depth detection algorithm?

I already have depth detection algorithm but I am stuck at Camera calibration because I cannot feed the camera stream to the algorithm. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib
 
# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(None)

def display_camera(camera_id):
    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("video-display")

    # create element
    source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("qtiqmmfsrc", "qmmf-source")
    framefilter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "frame-filter")
    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("waylandsink", "display")

    if not pipeline or not source or not framefilter or not sink:
        print("Create element failed")
        return

    source.set_property("camera", camera_id)

    # Modify the properties for framefilter
    if camera_id == 0:
        framefilter.set_property("caps",
                                 Gst.caps_from_string("video/x-raw,format=NV12,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080"))
    else:
        framefilter.set_property("caps",
                                 Gst.caps_from_string("video/x-raw,format=NV12,framerate=15/1,width=1280,height=720"))

    # Modify the properties for sink
    sink.set_property("x", 200)
    sink.set_property("y", 200)
    sink.set_property("width", 1280)
    sink.set_property("height", 720)

    # Build the pipeline
    pipeline.add(source)
    pipeline.add(framefilter)
    pipeline.add(sink)

    if not source.link(framefilter):
        print("ERROR: Could not link source to framefilter")
        return
    if not framefilter.link(sink):
        print("ERROR: Could not link framefilter to sink")
        return

    # Start playing
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    print("Started Liveview for camera %d" % camera_id)

    return pipeline
# Start display pipelines for the cameras
camera_id1 = 2
pipeline_str = display_camera(camera_id1)

camera_id2 = 1
pipeline_str2 = display_camera(camera_id2)

# Open video capture for recording
#cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
#cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline_str2, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

#cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
#cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(display_camera(1))
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(display_camera(2))

# Check if the video capture objects were successfully opened
if not cap1.isOpened() or not cap2.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open cameras for recording")
    exit()

num = 0

while True:
    success1, img1 = cap1.read()
    success2, img2 = cap2.read()

    if not success1 or not success2:
        print("Failed to read from cameras")
        break

    k = cv2.waitKey(5)
 
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
        cv2.imwrite('images/stereoLeft/imageL' + str(num) + '.png', img1)
        cv2.imwrite('images/stereoright/imageR' + str(num) + '.png', img2)
        print("images saved!")
        num += 1

    cv2.imshow('Camera 1', img1)
    cv2.imshow('Camera 2', img2)

    # Check for keyboard input
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

# Stop and cleanup the pipelines
pipeline_str.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
pipeline_str2.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

# Release and destroy all windows before termination
cap1.release()
cap2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output of this code is: Livestream from camera 1 and I can only see one camera window opening. It is not getting fed into rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. How can I access OV9282 MIPI stereo camera's using Gstreamer?

There are two cameras on RB5, the main color camera (large) and the side gray tracking camera (OV9282). You can replace waylandsink with appsink, which allows you to capture them.
If you are familiar with ROS (Robot Operating System). This repository has the related code and a launch script to launch both camera streams.
https://github.com/AutonomousVehicleLaboratory/rb5_ros/blob/main/rb5_vision/launch/rb_camera_both_ocv.launch

2. How to feed that that pipeline to do depth detection algorithm?

I am not familiar with GStreamer but with ROS you can have two node (process) running to get data from each camera. And create another node that subscribes to the two streams and feed to your algorithm.